# Martingale related to exponential martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Hello everyone if have the following task:
Prove that the process $Y_t=(B_t+t)\exp(-B_t-t/2)$ is a martingale.
I know that the stochastic exponential $X_t=\exp(B_t-t/2)$ is a martingale, where $B_t$ is the standard Brownian Motion.

What I have got so far is the following:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\mathbb{E}\left[Y_t|\mathscr{F}_s\right] & = \mathbb{E}[(B_t+t)\exp(-B_t-t/2)|\mathscr{F}_s] \\
& = \mathbb{E}[B_t\exp(B_t-t/2)|\mathscr{F}_s]+t\mathbb{E}[\exp(B_t-t/2|\mathscr{F}_s)]
\end{alignat*}

Now the second term is equal to $t\exp(B_s-s/2)$.

For the first term I calculated:
$$
\mathbb{E}[B_t\exp(B_t-t/2)|\mathscr{F}_s]=\exp(-t/2)\mathbb{E}[B_t\exp(B_t-B_s)\exp(B_s)|\mathscr{F}_s]
$$

We can take the term $\exp(-B_s)$ out of the integral and have left $\mathbb{E}[B_t\exp(B_t-B_s)|\mathscr{F}_s]$.

Now I think we can split the expectation as $B_t$ is independent of $(B_t-B_s)$.
Hence we get 
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\mathbb{E}[B_t\exp(B_t-B_s)|\mathscr{F}_s] & = B_s\mathbb{E}[\exp(B_t-B_s)|\mathscr{F}_s]\\
& = B_s\exp(1/2(t-s))\\
\end{alignat*}

So all in all $\mathbb{E}[Y_t|\mathscr{F}_s]=B_s\exp(B_s-s/2)+t\exp(B_s-s/2)\neq Y_s$

My question is where I went wrong. Any hints on how to solve the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $B_t$ is not independent from $B_t-B_s$, and therefore your computations for the second term are wrong.

Comment: Thanks, any hint on how i can calculate the expectation ?

Comment: Well, write $B_t = (B_t-B_s)+B_s$ and then split the conditional expectation into two parts (using the linearity).

Comment: got it now thank you very much